# Convert list of items in an Excel Table to comma-separated string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel (Table1) that has these column headings:  employee name, state licensed, and license status.  A sample of the table would be:

```
John Adams  NY  Active
John Adams  PA  Active
John Adams  NJ  Inactive
Ralph Ames  MS  Active
Ed Turner   MS  Pending
```

I want to set up a summary tab that has one row per employee with a column for active licenses, pending licenses, and inactive licenses, and those cells would display a comma-separated list of the appropriate state codes.  For example:

```
Name        Active   Pending   Inactive
John Adams  NY, PA             NJ
Ralph Ames  MS
Ed Turner            MS
```

I'm just curious about the best way to get to this custom list.  I wrote the function below which seems to work fine, and it runs faster than I expected, but it just seems inefficient because it loops through the entire table every time, and I've pasted formulas referencing this function to a few hundred cells:

```
Function comma_state_list(the_name As String, the_status As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oLo As ListObject
    Dim oCol As ListColumns

    Set ws = Worksheets("State Licenses")
    Set oLo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set oCol = oLo.ListColumns

    For i = 1 To oLo.ListRows.Count
        If oLo.Range(i, 1).Value = the_name And oLo.Range(i, 3) = the_status Then
            comma_state_list = comma_state_list & oLo.Range(i, 4) & ", "
        End If
    Next i

    If Len(comma_state_list) = 0 Then
        comma_state_list = ""
    Else
        comma_state_list = Left(comma_state_list, Len(comma_state_list) - 2)
    End If
End Function
```

Is there a way to maybe use VBA to run a SQL-like query against the table so I'm just looping through the SQL result instead of the entire table every time?  I was thinking this would help to alphabetize the summary list too.  Or maybe there's some other better way I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Have you worked with scripting dictionaries before? I think that would probably be a good option.

Comment: @DavidZemens: I have not heard of scripting dictionaries, but I will look into that now.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be a function? Could it not just be a macro that you run to update (or re-create) the list?

Comment: Thanks, David!  @NickSlash:  I thought about that, but then I worried about properly triggering that macro to make sure the summary tab was always in sync.  Now that you say that though, I guess I could just call it on the Activate event of the summary tab, and unless the workbook is shared, that should always work.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Might be better to use the change event of your source sheet instead of re-running the macro on activate. I'm not sure how macros like that would handle being shared. Tracking changes to the source sheet and ignoring the summary sheet might be good, but I've not done anything with shared-books so no idea if its possible

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here is an example using Scripting Dictionaries.

I have this table on one worksheet:

[image: Initial table list of license status by state]

And the output should produce a new worksheet with summary data like:

[image: Output summary data one row per employee name]

I tried to document it pretty thoroughly but let me know if you have any questions about it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim wsCurr As Worksheet: Set wsCurr = ActiveSheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet 'output container'
Dim rowNum As Long 'row number for output'

'Scripting dictionaries:'
Dim inactiveDict As Object
Dim activeDict As Object
Dim key As Variant

'Table variables'
Dim rng As Range 'table of data'
Dim r As Long 'row iterator for the table range.'

'information about each employee/row'
Dim empName As String
Dim state As String
Dim status As String

'Create our dictionaries:'
Set activeDict = Nothing
Set inactiveDict = Nothing
Set activeDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set inactiveDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set rng = Range("A1:C6") 'better to set this dynamically, this is just an example'

For r = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
    empName = rng(r, 1).Value
    state = rng(r, 2).Value
    status = rng(r, 3).Value

    Select Case UCase(status)
        Case "ACTIVE"
            AddItemToDict activeDict, empName, state

        Case "INACTIVE"

            AddItemToDict inactiveDict, empName, state

    End Select
Next

'Add a new worksheet with summary data'

Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=wsCurr)
With wsNew
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Active"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Inactive"

    rowNum = 2

    'Create the initial table with Active licenses'
    For Each key In activeDict
        .Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = key
        .Cells(rowNum, 2).Value = activeDict(key)
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Next

    'Now, go over this list with inactive licenses'
    For Each key In inactiveDict
        If activeDict.Exists(key) Then
            rowNum = Application.Match(key, .Range("A:A"), False)
        Else:
            rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsNew.Range("A:A")) + 1
            .Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = key
        End If

        .Cells(rowNum, 3).Value = inactiveDict(key)
    Next
End With

'Cleanup:
Set activeDict = Nothing
Set inactiveDict = Nothing


End Sub


Sub AddItemToDict(dict As Object, empName As String, state As String)
'since we will use the same methods on both dictionary objects, '
' it would be best to subroutine this action:'
Dim key As Variant

'check to see if this employee already exists'
If UBound(dict.Keys) = -1 Then
    dict.Add empName, state
Else:
    If Not dict.Exists(empName) Then
    'If IsError(Application.Match(empName, dictKeys, False)) Then
        'employee doesn't exist, so add to the dict'
        dict.Add empName, state
    Else:
        'employee does exist, so update the list:'
        'concatenate the state list'
        state = dict(empName) & ", " & state
        'remove the dictionary entry'
        dict.Remove empName
        'add the updated dictionary entry'
        dict.Add empName, state
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, David--I'll test this out.  I should point out that my summary tab will sort of be a "living" tab that should just update as data is added/modified...should I call the scripting dictionaries on the change event of the data worksheet (and of course modify the code to update the existing summary instead of creating a new one)?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `dict.Exists(key)` function? is `Application.Match` better?

Comment: @NickSlash because I didn't know about it :)  let me test & edit with that suggestion!

Comment: Adding the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (scrrun.dll) will add dictionaries to VBA so you can use `Dim dict as Scripting.Dictionary` and see all the methods and stuff which is helpful :)

Comment: Definitely good to know @NickSlash ! I do hesitate to use too many references just because it makes the code slightly less "portable" for other users (because I usually forget that they also have to add those references...)

Comment: @rryanp You could call this on the _Change event for the worksheet. Alternatively, I would probably just add a CommandButton to the sheet to manually call the function when needed, but if it's something that is updated frequently, you may prefer to use the Change event.

Comment: @DavidZemens--I really appreciate your help.  I am curious though what the advantage of using the scripting dictionaries is?  If it's called each time and loops through all the records each time, is there an advantage to using them over what NickSlash had originally suggested (a macro to update/recreate the lists each time it's needed)?  I would have thought maybe these dictionaries are maintained in memory to speed up the process, but it appears that they get recreated each time the code runs.  (Forgive me if I'm missing something...still trying to wrap my head around it.)  Thanks again.

Comment: @rryanp this *is* a macro that updates/recreates the lists each time it's needed :).  Even if you were to store that list physically, e.g., on a hidden worksheet, whatever macro you devise would ultimately have to load that list in to memory - IOW "recreating" the list by iterating over all of the list items each time.