# How to look up for multiple values and convert them in to a horizontal table in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table like below in excel spread sheet

```
A   1
A   2
B   12
B   4
B   56
B   68
C   7
C   8
C   34
D   10
D   11
```

i need to convert the table as below
    First entry Second entry    Third entry Fourth  entry

```
A   1   2   -   -
B   12  4   56  68
C   7   8   34  
D   10  11
```

Comment: Can you make more clear the data you are providing as an example?

Comment: Table contains 2 columns- 1st column has entries A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D and second column has their corresponding values 1,2,12,4,56,68,7,8,34,10,11 . I have to convert the table to another table where 1st column has unique values (A,B,C,D) and their values as corresponding columns. If A has values (1,2) in first table, in second table it should look like A 1 2

Comment: And the result you want to obtain?

Comment: I mentioned the result to be obtained as second table A 1 2                                                       B 12 4 56 68                                                                                                       C 7 8 34                                                                                                                    D 10 11

Comment: There are a few ways you can do it. Similar question here with some of them. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15754501/212869

Comment: see [Aggregate, Collate and Transpose rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440349/aggregate-collate-and-transpose-rows-into-columns). There are many others. This question gets asked in one form or another a couple of times a week.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your list of letters (assumed to be in ColumnA starting in Row1) is sorted and you have a separate list of just one each of those letters (say starting in D1) then a formula may achieve the results you want:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$D1)>COLUMN()-5,OFFSET(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D1,$A:$A,0)),COLUMN()-5,1),"")
```

In F1, copied down to suit and then all formulae copied across until an entire column is blank.